# IPTables block ALL packets to port 2001

Tags: iptables

so I need to block all packets to port 2001 in order to stop Chargen amplified floods on my server. Chargen amplified floods hit port 2001. This is what I have tried, but when I look in IPTraf, i still see packets coming in on port 2001:

```
iptables -A INPUT -p tcp --dport 2001 -j DROP
iptables -A INPUT -p udp --dport 2001 -j DROP
```

Please help!

Comment: System administration questions are more appropriate for serverfault.com. This isn't a programming question.

Comment: This belongs on serverfault.com

Answer (score 3):

Iptables can't stop packets coming in over the wire, it will only prevent further processing of them. So it's completely normal to see the unwanted traffic in packet dumps and similar tools.

Comment: So basically I cannot stop a chargen flood with IPTables?

Comment: No, you will have to work with your upstream provider / ISP in that case.

Comment: What would happen if I set IPTables to block every IP that sends a packet to port 2001?

Comment: That's what your example is doing already. IPTables cannot prevent packets from traveling down the wire. If your problem is that your incoming bandwidth is consumed by unwanted traffic, you'll need to work with your ISP to filter this traffic at their end.

Comment: Ok I have asked my host to block all traffic to port 2001, thanks!